# Windows batch script: ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION + For Loop not working as expected

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm not sure how to make the following code work. The loop is not returning all supposed files and `%%~FI` only expands at the beginning of the `FOR` loop. By the time the last command executes, `"%%~FI"` yields a literal string rather than expanding to the desired file name:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%I IN (*.foo *.bar) DO (
    SET OFileBase=%%~DPNI
    ECHO "%%~FI" REM Expands correctly at this point
    :WhileLoop2
    IF EXIST "!OFileBase!.baz" (
        SET /A SuffixIndex += 1
        SET OFileBase=%%~DPNI [!SuffixIndex!]
        GOTO WhileLoop2
    )
    ECHO "%%~FI" REM Expands no more, now a literal string?!
    fooparser.exe --input "%%~FI" - | bazmaker.exe - "!OFileBase!.baz"
)
ENDLOCAL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%I IN (*.foo *.bar) DO (
    SET OFileBase=%%~DPNI
    ECHO "%%~FI" REM Expands correctly at this point
    call :WhileLoop2 "%%~DPNI"
    ECHO "%%~FI" REM Expands no more, now a literal string?!
    fooparser.exe --input "%%~FI" - | bazmaker.exe - "!OFileBase!.baz"
)
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:WhileLoop2
IF EXIST "!OFileBase!.baz" (
 SET /A SuffixIndex += 1
 SET OFileBase=%~1 [!SuffixIndex!]
 GOTO WhileLoop2
)
goto :eof
```

Always difficult working with an isolated segment of a batch - especially one that's obviously been santitised further.

Your problem is attempting to use a label within a block statement (a parenthesised series of statements). Not a good idea - confuses `FOR` and terminates the loop.

Since you are using the metavariable `%%I` within the inner loop, pass it as a quoted parameter (in case `%%I` contains separators) to a subroutine, then access the value within the subroutine as `%~1` which removes the quotes.